# SQL showing current timestamp in different formats Mysql

Tags: mysql, timestamp-with-timezone, sql-timestamp

I need to show current UTC timestamp in a format '2021/05/10**T**18:30:36**Z**'

```
SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP() FROM XYZ
```

gives me `2021-05-10 18:30:36`

how do i add the / instead of - and use T and Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select DATE_FORMAT(UTC_TIMESTAMP(),'%Y/%m/%dT%TZ')

2021/05/10T18:51:07Z
```

Note that `T` doesn't really mean anything. And `Z` means *UTC ZERO timezone*, which is always the case with the UTC_TIMESTAMP function. Thus I have somewhat "hardcoded" those letters at the right place , and they are not real variables accepted by DATE_FORMAT()